# virtualbox- error on importing

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, virtualbox

I have offline computer with (computer_A):

```
OS: xubuntu (12.04)
virtualbox: 4.1.44   
guest: ubuntu 14.04
```

I have another computer(computer_B):

```
OS: windows 7
virtualbox: 5.0.6
guest: ubuntu 14.04
```

Im trying to export the OS as image from computer_B to computer_A.

the export process (on computer_B):

```
file -> export -> choose OS to expoet -> export as ovf file -> burned to CD 
insert the CD to computer_A -> file -> import -> choose the ovf file
```

the process stops with the error log:

```
filed to import appliance  **/**/**/filename.ovf
element in ovf contains a medium attachment for the disk image 
*** some kind of serial number ***  but the ovf describes no such image
```

what is wrong with the process? is it the version of virtualbox? 
Ill be happy for some guidance.

thanks.